# android file operation,open, fails

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, embedded-linux

I am using the ndk toolchain to build the following code to test the capacity of android's file operations.
And, in /data, the permission of read or write is no doubt Ok. But, I am confused as to why fopen() does not work and returns NULL.
Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
void main()
{
    int fd;
    int count = 128;
    int offset = 32;
    int ret;
    char buf[1024]="hi ! this is pwrite.";
    char pathname[128] = "/data/pwrite.txt";
    /*fd = fopen(pathname, O_WRONLY);*/
    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(pathname, "rb");
    if(infile==NULL) printf("fopen error  \n");
    /*if(fd==-1)printf("open error \n");*/
    if((ret = pwrite(fd, buf, count, offset))==-1)
    {
        printf("pwrite error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("pwrite success\n");
        printf("the writed data is:%s", buf);
    }
}
```

When I run the code directly in Android, it prompts the following:

```
# ./test
fopen error  
pwrite error
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try char pathname[128] = "//data//pwrite.txt";

Comment: i have try ur idea,but it also fails.but,thx anyway.Any other idea?

Comment: okey, please try this `infile = fopen( *pathname, "rb");`

Comment: jni/test.c:16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'fopen' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/home/kaiwii/android-ndk-r7/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include/stdio.h:232: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'

Comment: have you given this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>' in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: in fopen(),the argument 1 only accept a point.So^any idea?thx

Comment: please come to this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/casual-chat)

Comment: i have try to add the permission declaration,but it fail again

Comment: Look at to my above chat room link and please come to there.

Comment: @Lucifer WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not relevant for the /data partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given `rb` mode while opening the file, which simply means reading binary file. Now you are performing the `write` operation which is wrong. You should give the write mode as follows,

```
infile = fopen(pathname, "wb");
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your file mode problem,

```
"/data/pwrite.txt"
```

Should not be a location accessable for writing by an android application userid, or even (on a secured device) the adb shell user.

As of approximately android 2.2 up (but subject to change at any time), /data/local is usable as scratch area by the adb shell user.  For code within an application, each application userid has it's own package-unique private storage area findable by one of the java-level api calls - I think it's something like getFilesDir() - which you really should use for portability rather than hardcode a path.

The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is relevant only if you wish to use the "external storage" (depending on the device this might be soldered down or an actual removable card) instead of the internal storage.  There again, you should really obtain the device specific path via an api call rather than non-portably assume that it is something like /mnt/sdcard